# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\ [ function name ]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my controller, I create a function `getFactorial`

```
public static function getFactorial($num)
{
    $fact = 1;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $num ;$i++)
        $fact = $fact * $i;
    return $fact;
}
```

Then, I use it like this

```
public function codingPuzzleProcess()
{

    $word     = strtoupper(Input::get('word'));
    $length   = strlen($word);
    $max_value = ($length * 26);
    $characters = str_split($word);

    $num = 1 ;
    $index = 1;

    sort($characters);

    foreach ( $characters as $character) {
        $num += getFactorial($index) * $index;
        $index ++;
    }

    return Redirect::to('/coding-puzzle')
        ->with('word', $word )
        ->with('num', $num )
        ->with('success','Submit successfully!');

}
```

For some reason, I keep getting this error

`Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\getFactorial()`

Can someone please teach me how to fix this error ?

Much appreciated in advance.

---

**CodeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use View, Input, Redirect;

class CodeController extends Controller {


    public function codingPuzzle()
    {
        return View::make('codes.puzzle');
    }

    public static function getFactorial($num)
    {
        $fact = 1;
        for($i = 1; $i <= $num ;$i++)
            $fact = $fact * $i;
        return $fact;
    }


    public function codingPuzzleProcess()
    {

        $word     = strtoupper(Input::get('word'));
        $length   = strlen($word);
        $max_value = ($length * 26);
        $characters = str_split($word);

        $num = 1 ;
        $index = 1;

        sort($characters);

        foreach ( $characters as $character) {
            $num += getFactorial($index) * $index;
            $index ++;
        }

        return Redirect::to('/coding-puzzle')
            ->with('word', $word )
            ->with('num', $num )
            ->with('success','Submit successfully!');

    }


}
```

Comment: in which class `getFactorial` is defined?

Comment: CodeController class.

Comment: `static::getFactorial($index)`. You should read up on OOP PHP programming.

Comment: `self::getFactorial($index)` should work as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

say you define the `static getFactorial` function inside a `CodeController`

then this is the way you need to call a static function, **because static properties and methods exists with in the class, not in the objects created using the class.**

```
CodeController::getFactorial($index);
```

----------------**UPDATE**----------------

To best practice I think you can put this kind of functions inside a separate file so you can maintain with more easily.

to do that

create a folder inside `app` directory and name it as `lib` (you can put a name you like).

this folder to needs to be autoload to do that add `app/lib` to `composer.json` as below. and run the `composer dumpautoload` command.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
                "app/commands",
                "app/controllers",
                ............
                "app/lib"
    ]
},
```

then files inside `lib` will autoloaded.

then create a file inside `lib`, i name it `helperFunctions.php`

inside that define the function.

```
if ( ! function_exists('getFactorial'))
{

    /**
     * return the factorial of a number
     *
     * @param $number
     * @return string
     */
    function getFactorial($date)
    {
        $fact = 1;

        for($i = 1; $i <= $num ;$i++)
            $fact = $fact * $i;

        return $fact;

     }
}
```

and call it anywhere within the app as

```
$fatorial_value = getFactorial(225);
```

Comment: First thank-you for you answer. Is static is the only way to do it ?

Comment: umm i think its not good to put this kind of function inside a class, ill update the answer

Comment: Thanks you for your update, and suggestion for a better way of doing this.

Comment: I update with more details,please have a look and let me know if you set it up correctly or any issues?

Comment: Hello, thank you for this solution. What is the use of function_exists?

Answer (score 10):

If they are in the same controller class, it would be:

```
foreach ( $characters as $character) {
    $num += $this->getFactorial($index) * $index;
    $index ++;
}
```

Otherwise you need to create a new instance of the class, and call the method, ie:

```
$controller = new MyController();
foreach ( $characters as $character) {
    $num += $controller->getFactorial($index) * $index;
    $index ++;
}
```